# Iterate nltk.tokenize across all rows of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tokenize

grateful for your help for what feels like a stupid question.  I've pulled a sqlite table into a pandas dataframe so I can tokenize and count the frequency of words from a series of tweets.

With the code below, I can produce this for the first tweet.  How do I iterate for the whole table?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("tweets.sqlite")
data = pd.read_sql_query("select tweet_text from tweets_new;", conn)

tokenizer=RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(data['tweet_text'][0])

words = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

unigram_df = pd.DataFrame(words.most_common(),
                             columns=["WORD","COUNT"])

unigram_df
```

When I change the value to anything other than a single row, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

I know there are other ways of doing this, but I need to do it along these lines because of how I intend to use the output next.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

I have tried:

```
%%time

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')  

print "Cleaning the tweets...\n"
for i in xrange(0,len(df)):
    if( (i+1)%1000000 == 0 ):  
        tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(df['tweet_text'][i])
        words = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)
```

This looks like it should work, but still only returns words from the first row.

Comment: Please post the code you've used when you say that you "change the value to anything other than a single row".

Comment: Thanks, edited with the approach I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be solved more concisely using [CountVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html). I'll give you an example. Given the following inputs:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd 

corpus_tweets = [['I love pizza and hambuerger'],['I love apple and chips'], ['The pen is on the table!!']]
df = pd.DataFrame(corpus_tweets, columns=['tweet_text'])
```

You can create your bag of words template with these few lines:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df.tweet_text)
```

You can print the obtained vocabulary:

```
count_vect.vocabulary_
# ouutput: {'love': 5, 'pizza': 8, 'and': 0, 'hambuerger': 3, 'apple': 1, 'chips': 2, 'the': 10, 'pen': 7, 'is': 4, 'on': 6, 'table': 9}
```

and get the dataframe with word counts:

```
df_count = pd.DataFrame(X_train_counts.todense(), columns=count_vect.get_feature_names())

   and  apple  chips  hambuerger  is  love  on  pen  pizza  table  the
0    1      0      0           1   0     1   0    0      1      0    0
1    1      1      1           0   0     1   0    0      0      0    0
2    0      0      0           0   1     0   1    1      0      1    2
```

If it is useful for you, you can merge the dataframe of the counts with the dataframe of the corpus:

```
pd.concat([df, df_count],  axis=1)

                    tweet_text  and  apple  chips  hambuerger  is  love  on  \
0  I love pizza and hambuerger    1      0      0           1   0     1   0   
1       I love apple and chips    1      1      1           0   0     1   0   
2    The pen is on the table!!    0      0      0           0   1     0   1   

   pen  pizza  table  the  
0    0      1      0    0  
1    0      0      0    0  
2    1      0      1    2
```

If you want to get the dictionary containing the `<word, count>` pairs for each document, at this point all you need to do is:

```
dict_count = df_count.T.to_dict()

{0: {'and': 1,
  'apple': 0,
  'chips': 0,
  'hambuerger': 1,
  'is': 0,
  'love': 1,
  'on': 0,
  'pen': 0,
  'pizza': 1,
  'table': 0,
  'the': 0},
 1: {'and': 1,
  'apple': 1,
  'chips': 1,
  'hambuerger': 0,
  'is': 0,
  'love': 1,
  'on': 0,
  'pen': 0,
  'pizza': 0,
  'table': 0,
  'the': 0},
 2: {'and': 0,
  'apple': 0,
  'chips': 0,
  'hambuerger': 0,
  'is': 1,
  'love': 0,
  'on': 1,
  'pen': 1,
  'pizza': 0,
  'table': 1,
  'the': 2}}
```

**Note**: turning `X_train_counts` which is a ***sparse numpy matrix*** into a dataframe is *not a good idea*. But it can be useful to understand and visualize the various steps of your model.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I won't bore you with the details, but I have been attempting this like this because it allows me to formulate a list of unique values plus frequency and insert this back into the sqlite db using sqlite syntax.  Your approach sounds sensible, but gives me other pain points.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the dictionary corresponding to this dataframe, and you would like to have the following structure: `{id_doc1: {word1: count1, ... wordN: countN}}, id_doc2: {word1: count1, ... wordN: countN} ,....}` quite right? You can get this quickly by doing: `df_count.T.to_dict ()`

Comment: Thanks so much @Massifox  Actually, what you have produced at step 2 and 3 is closest to what I need - column of unique values from all rows, and a column with the frequency of each word.  Why is it a bad idea to turn this into a dataframe?

Comment: @SiJo For reasons of efficiency. This operation is not very efficient for 2 reasons: 1) The resulting matrix is ​​sparse (with many values ​​at 0) and therefore it takes up memory unnecessarily, in fact CountVectorizer returns you a 'compressed' matrix to effectively represent this type of matrix. Creating a dataframe expands this matrix, losing the optimization and uselessly occupying much more memory than necessary, and pandas is not particularly efficient (used in this way) to manage this kind of problems.
2) Calculations become computationally more expensive due to the size of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Massifox.  I think in light of your comments I won't be able to scale the approach you've suggested.

Comment: If I can help you ask, as well. Meanwhile, if my answer helped you, accept it and voteup. Thanks @SiJo

Answer (score 0):

After creating the `DataFrame` loop over all the rows:

```
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
fdist = FreqDist()
for txt in data['tweet_text']:
      for word in tokenizer.tokenize(txt):
          fdist[word.lower()] += 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this out, but didn't seem to work.  When I try to call the dataframe, I get the following error:  AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'most_common'

Comment: The words frecuencies are in `fdist` (try `fdist.tabulate()`). There's no use of Pandas in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @luis.parravicini - I can tabulate with fdist.tabulate().  But I'm trying to produce a column of unique values from all rows, and a column with the frequency of each word.  Any idea how I can retabulate the output to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in this niche use case, here's the code I was eventually able to make work:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("tweets.sqlite")
data = pd.read_sql_query("select tweet_text from tweets_new;", conn)

alldata = str(data)

tokenizer=RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
tokens=tokenizer.tokenize(alldata)

words = nltk.FreqDist(tokens)

unigram_df = pd.DataFrame(words.most_common(),
                             columns=["WORD","COUNT"])
```

Thanks for your help everyone!